# Sorting in Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, kendo-grid

I am sorting Kendo grid dynamically.

```
var sortedName = $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SortingName)').val();
var sortedOrderName = $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SortingOrderName)').val();
```

`sort: { field: sortedName, dir: sortedOrderName }`,
it is working fine but this is sorting records by pagination. What I want is to sort all the data fetched from the database

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the remote data binding example: [Kendo Grid Remote-Data-Binding](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding)

Note the Data Source settings for serverPaging, serverFiltering and server sorting:

```
          dataSource: {
                        type: "odata",
                        transport: {
                            read: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                        },
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                    Freight: { type: "number" },
                                    ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                    OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                                    ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 20,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        serverSorting: true
                    }
```

Comment: This will append the sort options to the grid request.